# Getting "ValueError: Unknown activation function: PReLU" when I try to load a trained model that employes PReLU as the activation function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, activation-function, relu

As the title is self-descriptive, I'm getting the `ValueError: Unknown activation function: PReLU` error when I try to load my trained CNN model that employed the `PReLU` as the activation function for both Convolutional and Dense layers. How can I use this model? Is there a workaround?

p.s. I'm using the `load_model` function of `Keras` to load the model through the provided `.h5` file.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

When using advanced activation functions like PReLU, it is better is to use it with add() method and not wrapping it using the 'Activation' .
For example

```
activation_function = keras.layers.advanced_activations.PReLU(init='zero', weights=None)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=14, init='uniform'))
model.add(activation_function)
```